# "Awaiting AE decision" has lasted for nearly four months. What should I do?

Tags: publications

The status of my manuscript is "Awaiting AE decision", and it has lasted for nearly four months.
I have sent two pieces of mail to AE to inquire of the status, but I have not received any reply.
What does this situation mean? What should I do? 
..While, I am still waiting, no reply.

Comment: Contact the editor!

Comment: @Aditya: Should I contact the Editor in Chief? I have contacted the associate editor twice, but I did not receive any reply.

Comment: In some journals there is a senior editor who oversees different areas; othrers simply have an editor in chief who oversees everything. Depending on the journal contact one of these to check the status of your paper.

Comment: You may wish to clarify in your post the entire timeline of your submission. E.g., is this an initial submission? What is the total amount of time since your initial submission? On some systems, the status of a manuscript is not necessarily indicative of where it is in the system.

Comment: The initial version of this manuscript was submitted last year. It has gone through two rounds of peer reviews. The last version was resubmitted on May this year. I have sent a mail to EIC two days ago.  He has informed the AE. Now, the only thing I can do is wait.

Answer (score 4):

It could mean they're overworked or disorganized. Four months seems substantial.  Maybe you could try a phone call.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. 
Since I am not a native English speaker, I am afraid that I can not explain the whole things clearly through the phone. 
Maybe I should contact the editor in chief by e-mail and cc to AE. But I am not sure whether it is polite. This paper really means a lot to me.

Comment: A polite email inquiry can't do any harm.  (I thought you had already tried email, sorry.)

Comment: I have sent two mails to the AE. But I did not receive any reply.

Comment: Right, so now you propose to try emailing the editor in chief.  Sure.  Make it short and polite.  Ex. subject=status report of (paper)? // "I'm concerned about my (date) submission, which was confirmed on (date).  I have not had any news about it since.(date).  I have written to (name) on (date) and (date), but have not heard back from him/her..  Can you tell me what sort of time frame to keep in mind as I am awaiting news of my submission?  Thank you very much.  Sincerely, (full name)  *It's an example, you don't have to stick to this phrasing or structure.*

Comment: I have sent a mail to the EIC. Now, all I can do is crossing my fingers.

Answer (score 0):

Four months seems unreasonable. Either the AE is on leave or having a holiday trip with family or health issues. Anything is possible. However, it is the responsibility of the Editor-in-Chief to deal with such delays.

I would email (a final reminder email) to EIC, AEs and journal support staff regarding this and wait for a week to hear from them back on my email. If still, they are not responding, I will email them saying that "I am withdrawing the paper from your esteemed journal. Thank you for your earlier consideration."

Please note that there is no bottom by clicking which you can withdraw the paper. So, *be careful about it and try to make it as transparent as possible that you are withdrawing the paper because of the valid reason. Don't be greedy that if the paper is accepted after your mail, if at-all it gets accepted, you will go with acceptance. No, you can't. You should stick with your decision of withdrawl.*

Comment: This paper really means a lot to me. I do not think I have the courage to withdraw it. I have sent a mail to EIC two days ago. Hope it would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, I have spent five months and one year to deal with this paper.

Comment: Then you should wait and watch.

Comment: Yeah. Hope this paper could be accepted. Thank you for your help!